# Dose tdengine support json data type?

Tags: json, tdengine

In mysql, there is json data type, like this:[mysql json data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Where are the reference documents of json type in tdengine？

Answer (score 0):

Documentation goes here [TDengine SQL Data Type](https://www.taosdata.com/docs/cn/v2.0/taos-sql#data-type)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version, TDengine supports JSON type, but only for tag column.